# how to create a notification tab like facebook

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

I want to create a notification tab just like facebook currently im using timed requests but the idea has failed so how do I send (push) notifications to the client do I use some thing like comet?

Comment: What do you mean the timed request failed? An AJAX request to the server every 30 seconds (or less if your server is quick enough) would work fine.

Comment: no the ideas great but not possible because my server crashed 3 times when the interval was set to 1.5 min

Comment: then you may need to optimise your server-script for quick access to users notifications, or consider upgrading your server.  I'm pretty sure this is the standard way of doing this work.
the alternative would be Sockets, but this is major overkill to get a number from a DB on the server!!

Comment: ok can I use reverse ajax?wht are the pros and cons of reverse ajax

Comment: Reverse AJAX, is technically not a real thing, its still from Client-> server, if your thinking Comet, then you will find you need a pretty good server, as this will Lock threads on your webserver waiting for an event to happen, so if you have more people than threads, your server will be down for any new visitors..
Either way you look at it, it sounds like you need to consider upgrading your server